# How to solve error occurring in the following vhdl code?

Tags: vhdl

The error is: "ERROR:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit  on signal nfw".

```
process(rst_n,dword_int,sync_csw_reg,sync_dw_reg)
begin
  if(rst_n='1')then
      noofwords<="00000";
      no_words<="00000";
      nfw<='1';
  elsif(falling_edge(sync_csw_reg) and dword_int(10)='0' and nfw='1' )then
      noofwords<=dword_int(0 to 4);
      check_nfw<=dword_int(0 to 4);
  end if;
end process;

process(sync_dw_reg,noofwords)
begin
  if(falling_edge(sync_dw_reg))then
    if(no_words = noofwords)then
      no_words<="00000";
      nfw<='1';
    else
      no_words<= no_words+'1';
      nfw<='0';
    end if;
  end if;
end process;
```

Comment: Exact duplicate (same user): [Can anybody let me know what is the problem with the following vhdl code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6043975/can-anybody-let-me-know-what-is-the-problem-with-the-following-vhdl-code)

Comment: @Paul: It's not a duplicate but a follow-up.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you are assigning the signal `nfw` from within two processes. That's not possible. You would have to use two different signals (if you need them) and somehow combine them combinationally. Resp.: You could add a `if (rst_n='1')` into the second process and assign the reset value of `nfw` there.